# Problem with program to list primes below integer using arrays and nested loops

Tags: arrays, c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10000


int main(void)

{

  int a[MAX_SIZE];
  int N;

  int L;  /* the current size of the list */

   /* read in the upper limit. Keep reading until
     a valid number between 3 and the maximum that
     can be handled by the array is entered */


double b[10000];
    int j, i;
    L = 0;
    printf("Enter the upper limit:\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &N);
      } while (N<3 || N>MAX_SIZE+2);

  int prime;
  for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
  {
    prime = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < j; i++)
    {
      if (j % i == 0)
      {
        prime = 0;
        break;
      }

    }
    if (prime)
    {
      a[i] = j;
      L++;
    }
  }

  /* write out the result  - DO NOT CHANGE THIS */

  for(i=0;i<L;i++)
    printf("%d ",a[i]);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

Program needs to take an integer, calculate primes below that integer, print that list of primes.
I think my problem is related to the loops.
The program is calculating the primes but listing 0 if the number previously there isnt prime eg a[4] is now printing as 0
Any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: crvm, Is 1 a prime?  Code says yes.  Usually 1 is not considered a prime.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were trying to implement?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    int primes[MAX_SIZE];
    int primes_found = 0;
    int limit = 0;

    while (limit < 3)
    {
        printf("Enter the upper limit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
    }

    for (int candidate = 2; candidate <= limit && primes_found < MAX_SIZE; candidate++)
    {
        int divisor = 2;
        int is_prime = 1;
        while(is_prime && divisor < candidate)
            is_prime = candidate % divisor++ != 0;
        
        if (is_prime)
            primes[primes_found++] = candidate;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < primes_found ; i++)
        printf("%d ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In time, additional tips in order to make your code easier to follow. (1) Make sure to cleanup unused objects from your code (ex.: `double b[10000]`); (2) Be consistent with naming conventions, some were named with upper and some with lower (3); Be consistent with `{ }` placement, some were at the end of the line, some were at the beginning; (4) Be consistent with indentation, some of the code is misaligned; (5) Be consistent with formatting (ex.: `for (i = 2; i < j; i++)` and `for(i=0;i<L;i++)`); (6) Give variables relevant names (ex.: `primes[]` and `primes_found` instead of `a[]` and `L`)

Comment: To greatly speed things up `divisor < candidate` --> `divisor <= candidate/divisor`

Comment: Interesting! Or alternatively, the square root of candidate could also be used as a limit to the loop.

Comment: ... and how to form the _square root of candidate_?  Using `sqrt()` is expensive and prone to issues regarding using floating point for an integer problem.  IAC, `candidate/divisor` is cost free when next to `candidate%divisor` and using a good compiler.

Comment: Again, interesting! Even though they are both possible solutions to eliminate unnecessary iterations, mathematically speaking.

Comment: @crvmn, by the way, I forgot to mention that this answer also addresses (1) 1 not being a prime number; (2) checking the exact maximum index of `primes[]`, see the for loop condition; (3) eliminate unnecessary break statement by using a loop condition, see while loop; (4) excluding the limit when it is a prime number, see for loop condition.